# Duplicate an HTML file (and its content) with a different name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML file with some Javascript and css applied on.
I would like to duplicate that file, make like file1.html, file2.html, file3.html,... 

All of that using Javascript, Jquery or something like that !
The idea is to create a different page (from that kind of template) that will be printed afterwards with different data in it (from a XML file).
I hope it is possible !
Feel free to ask more precision if you want !

Thank you all by advance

Note: I do not want to copy the content only but the entire file.

Edit: I Know I should use server-side language, I just don't have the option ):

Comment: Javascript isn't server side. You need use some server-side langugage like PHP.

Comment: Even if it were possible it's not a correct approach. As @AndreaGesti suggested, use some server-side language (PHP, Ruby, Python...)

Comment: I know I should use server side language but I do not have that option... ):

Comment: If your XML is static, create a script that generates `n` static HTML files locally and upload those files to the server. If your XML is dynamic, you're gonna need some server-side language even if it's node.js (so, javascript) if you only use JS+Ajax on client side to update the content...

Comment: I could maybe use some XML to generates the HTML and JS to populate it from an other XML file ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you could go about implementing something similar to what you are describing. Which implementation you should use would depend on exactly what your goals are.

First of all, I would recommend some sort of template system such as VueJS, AngularJS or React. However, given that you say you don't have the option of using a server side language, I suspect you won't have the option to implement one of these systems.

My next suggestion, would be to build your own 'templating system'. A simple implementation that may suit your needs could be something mirroring the following:

In your primary file (root file) which you want to route or copy the other files through to, you could use JS to include the correct HTML files. For example, you could have JS conditionally load a file depending on certain circumstances by putting something like the following after a conditional statement:

Note that while doing this could optimize your server's data usage (as it would only serve required files and not everything all the time), it would also probably increase loading times. Your site would need to wait for the additional HTTP request to come through and for whatever requested content to load & render on the client. While this sounds very slow it has the potential of not being that bad if you don't have too many discrete requests, and none of your code is unusually large or computationally expensive.

If using vanilla JS, the following snippet will illustrate the above:
In a script that comes loaded with your routing file:

```
  function read(text) {
      var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest;
      xhr.open('GET',text);
      xhr.onload=show;
      xhr.send();
  }

  function show() {
      var text = this.response;
      document.body.innerHTML = text;//you can replace document.body with whatever element you want to wrap your imported HTML 
  }

  read(path/to/file/on/server);
```

Note a couple of things about the above code. If you are testing on your computer (ie opening your html file on a browser, with a path like file://__) without a local server, you will get some sort of cross origin request error when trying to make an XML request. To bypass this error, either test your code on an actual server (not ideal constantly pushing code, I know) or, preferably, set up a local testing server. If this is something you would want to explore, its not that difficult to do, let me know and I'd be happy to walk you through the process.

Alternately, you could implement the above loading system with jQuery and the `.load()` function. http://api.jquery.com/load/

If none of the above solutions work for you, let me know more specifically what it is that you need, and I'll be happy to give a more useful/ relevant answer!

Comment: I am currently doing kind of a template thing. I have static HTML that I fill with information from XML using Jquery, but there is some of those static HTML that I need like 3 time or maybe 20 depending on the input from the XML. I am doing a reporting thing based on the configuration of a product, like for exemple screen1.html screen2.html, that are all configuration for the client. And I don't know how many file I'll need.